# how to hover over multiple elements using Python

Tags: python, selenium, hover

I'm trying to hover over not only one point but the multiple points after one by one.
The point here means each user's image profile (There are 5 of them for each page).
The reason why I do this is that I try to parse each user's link profile.
But tricky part is that the html codes are hidden. In other words, it doesn't show up unless if I hover over each user's profile or picture.
Let me jump straight to my code.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

#Incognito Mode
option=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

#Open Chrome
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/chromedriver.exe",options=option)

#Get the link
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g60742-d7951369-or20-Groove_Stone_Getaway-Asheville_North_Carolina.html")

#This is the first time for me to use Xpath so please understand if there's something wrong with my code
profile=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mainContent']")
profile_pic=profile.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ui_avatar large']")

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(profile_pic).perform()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(profile_pic).click().perform()

profile_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span//a[contains(@href,"/Profile/")]').get_attribute("href")
print (profile_box)
```

How do I hover over the multiple users (who has the same Xpath codes) in this case?

===============================updated codes==========================

```
num_page=0

#Incognito Mode
option=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

#Open Chrome
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/chromedriver.exe",options=option)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#Type in URL you want to visit
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g60742-d7951369-Groove_Stone_Getaway-Asheville_North_Carolina.html")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

#loop over multiple pages.
for j in range(1,16,1):
    time.sleep(5)
    try:

        #finds all the comments or profile pics
        profile_pic= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='prw_rup prw_reviews_member_info_hsx']//div[@class='ui_avatar large']")

        time.sleep(3)

        for i in profile_pic:
                #clicks all the profile pic one by one
                ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i).perform()
                time.sleep(2)
                ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i).click().perform()
                time.sleep(4)
                #print the href or link value
                profile_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span//a[contains(@href,"/Profile/")]').get_attribute("href")
                time.sleep(3)
                print (profile_box)
    except:
        pass


    #click the next button to go to the next page.
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next')
    #Another element is covering the element you are to click.
    #You could use execute_script() to click on this.    
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)

    #After a certain number of pages, use break function to escape from the loop.
    num_page=num_page+1
    if num_page==14:
        break
```

Thanks to Yosuva A, I could solve how to hover over the multiple users in the same page and could parse the data. I tried to develop the code more so that I loop over the multiple pages (each page includes 5 users). 
My updated code surely iterates through multiple pages but at some random point, the code only parse the same user profile links. 
Here's the output example I get:

```
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/Cftra
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/jessicarZ577PF
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/BackPacker115730
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/nanm
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/kukimama
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/ThreeColeys
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/AlanS990
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/S5227HKlisas
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/H1493VRmatthewt
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/H1493VRmatthewt
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/H1493VRmatthewt
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/H1493VRmatthewt
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/H1493VRmatthewt
```

I thought I needed to add time sleep function so put those in several lines but still having the same issue. Could someone help me out and this occurs and how to get over it?
Thank you.

Comment: I think I already gave you the answer in another post? Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Python example

This code will click all the profile pics one by one and it will print the href value.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g60742-d7951369-or20-Groove_Stone_Getaway-Asheville_North_Carolina.html");

#finds all the comments or profile pics
profile_pic= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='prw_rup prw_reviews_member_info_hsx']//div[@class='ui_avatar large']")

for i in profile_pic:
        #clicks all the profile pic one by one
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i).perform()
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i).click().perform()
        time.sleep(2)
        #print the href or link value
        profile_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span//a[contains(@href,"/Profile/")]').get_attribute("href")
        print (profile_box)

driver.quit()
```

Output

> ```
> https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/861kellyd
> https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/JLERPercy
> https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/rayn817
> https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/grossla
> https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/kapmem
> ```

### Java Example

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./lib/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g60742-d7951369-or20-Groove_Stone_Getaway-Asheville_North_Carolina.html");

        //finds all the comments or profiles
        List<WebElement> profile= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='prw_rup prw_reviews_member_info_hsx']//div[@class='ui_avatar large']"));

        for(int i=0;i<profile.size();i++)
        {
            //Hover on user profile photo
            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            builder.moveToElement(profile.get(i)).perform();
            builder.moveToElement(profile.get(i)).click().perform();
            //Wait for user details pop-up
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span//a[contains(@href,'/Profile/')]")));
            //Extract the href value
            String hrefvalue=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span//a[contains(@href,'/Profile/')]")).getAttribute("href");
            //Print the extracted value
            System.out.println(hrefvalue);
        }
        //close the browser
        driver.quit(); 

    }

}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your python code. It works amazingly fine. I learned a lot! thank you.

Comment: just noticed that your code works but sometimes it scrapes the same user links in a row. something like this. 
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/JLERPercy
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/rayn817 https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/rayn817 https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/rayn817

Comment: We can write a code to populate it in format which you want

Comment: I'm not sure it's a matter of my computing power or speed but when I added time.sleep function before printing out href or link value, it works better than before.

Comment: After putting a time sleep function, it works great since your code scrapes all 4 profile links but an issue occurs for the last fifth profile. Error message says unable to locate the Xpath element and in the chrome browser, it doesn't click the last element but just hangs there.